# How to display company name on checkout page in Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, shipping-address

I want to display the company name from customer address on checkout page in Magento2.1

It should be visible in shipping address section as well as side bar.

How can I do it?[image: Screen1]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add company name or any other address field in

For add new field in **shipping adress section**, override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html`

For add new field in **sidebar ship to section**, override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html`

For override create **requirejs-config.js** at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html':
                'Vendor_Module/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html',

            'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html':
                'Vendor_Module/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html'
        }
    }
};
```

Now add `<!-- ko text: address().company --><!-- /ko -->` in overrided file where you want to display company field.

like in

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html

```
<div class="shipping-address-item" data-bind="css: isSelected() ? 'selected-item' : 'not-selected-item'">
    <!-- ko text: address().prefix --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().firstname --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko text: address().lastname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().suffix --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: address().street --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: address().company -->
    <!-- ko text: address().city --><!-- /ko -->, <!-- ko text: address().region --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().postcode --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: getCountryName(address().countryId) --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: address().telephone --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element' } -->
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute' } -->
            <!-- ko text: element[attribute].value --><!-- /ko -->
         <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: (address().isEditable()) -->
    <button type="button"
            class="action edit-address-link"
            data-bind="click: editAddress, visible: address().isEditable()">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: selectAddress" class="action action-select-shipping-item">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Ship Here'"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: already ShiperHQ_Shiper module is overriding it so I overridden ShiperHQ_Shiper in requirejs-config.js but not working

Comment: hi prince, could you please help for requirejs file, it gives error "Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html" not found, well I have placed 'Vendor_Module/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html', under my module successfully

Comment: @Prince Patel, Can I display the loggedin customer mail id in the place of the company name?

Comment: @Ramya Yes, you can.

Comment: @PrincePatel, Can you please explain this?.In my html I have added this code 
<p data-bind="html: getCustomAttributeVal()"></p>
In js file,
getCustomAttributeVal: function() {
      return "my customer attribute value";
 }
Actually, I want one customer attribute value. So I'm wondering to get the value in Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.js

Comment: We're using ShipperHQ and I had to patch a file using composer-patches in order to get Company to show: https://gist.github.com/erikhansen/d80b54dca751d92a585fea84651fbac3

Answer (score 4):

You can simply override the knockout template file in your module

> /magentoroot/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html

The address object is already has the data you want so just add this line

```
<!-- ko text: address().company --><!-- /ko --><br/>
```

Full Code

```
<div class="shipping-address-item" data-bind="css: isSelected() ? 'selected-item' : 'not-selected-item'">
    <!-- ko text: address().prefix --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().firstname --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko text: address().lastname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().suffix --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: address().company --><!-- /ko --><br/> 
    <!-- ko text: address().street --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: address().city --><!-- /ko -->, <!-- ko text: address().region --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().postcode --><!-- /ko -->  
    <!-- ko text: getCountryName(address().countryId) --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: address().telephone --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element' } -->
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute' } -->
            <!-- ko text: element[attribute].value --><!-- /ko -->
         <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: (address().isEditable()) -->
    <button type="button"
            class="action edit-address-link"
            data-bind="click: editAddress, visible: address().isEditable()">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: selectAddress" class="action action-select-shipping-item">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Ship Here'"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: no need to require.js file for this ?, as I tried this, but its now working, any other changes we have to do for the same ?

Answer (score 3):

To bring company name in shipping address section, @princepatel answer is fine. However, we need to put condition to check whether its empty. So i will provide with that specific condition.

To bring the company name in shipping address section in checkout page override

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html

to

> /app/design/frontend/your-vendor-name/your-theme-name/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html

Then add

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="shipping-address-item" css="'selected-item' : isSelected() , 'not-selected-item':!isSelected()">
    <text args="address().prefix"/> <text args="address().firstname"/> <text args="address().middlename"/>
    <text args="address().lastname"/> <text args="address().suffix"/><br/>
    <if args="address().company">
        <text args="address().company"/><br/>
    </if>
    <text args="_.values(address().street).join(', ')"/><br/>
    <text args="address().city "/>, <span text="address().region"></span> <text args="address().postcode"/><br/>
    <text args="getCountryName(address().countryId)"/><br/>
    <a if="address().telephone" attr="'href': 'tel:' + address().telephone" text="address().telephone"></a><br/>

    <each args="data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element'">
        <each args="data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute'">
            <if args="typeof element[attribute] === 'object'">
                <if args="element[attribute].label">
                    <text args="element[attribute].label"/>
                </if>
                <ifnot args="element[attribute].label">
                    <if args="element[attribute].value">
                        <text args="element[attribute].value"/>
                    </if>
                </ifnot>
            </if>
            <if args="typeof element[attribute] === 'string'">
                <text args="element[attribute]"/>
            </if><br/>
        </each>
    </each>

    <button visible="address().isEditable()" type="button"
            class="action edit-address-link"
            click="editAddress">
        <span translate="'Edit'"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- ko if: (!isSelected()) -->
    <button type="button" click="selectAddress" class="action action-select-shipping-item">
        <span translate="'Ship Here'"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

To bring the company name in shipping address residing under order summary section, override

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html

to

> /app/design/frontend/your-vendor-name/your-theme-name/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html

Then add

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<if args="visible()">
    <text args="address().prefix"/> <text args="address().firstname"/> <text args="address().middlename"/>
    <text args="address().lastname"/> <text args="address().suffix"/><br/>
    <if args="address().company">
        <text args="address().company"/><br/> 
    </if>
    <text args="_.values(address().street).join(', ')"/><br/>
    <text args="address().city "/>, <span text="address().region"></span> <text args="address().postcode"/><br/>
    <text args="getCountryName(address().countryId)"/><br/>
    <a if="address().telephone" attr="'href': 'tel:' + address().telephone" text="address().telephone"></a><br/>

    <each args="data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element'">
        <each args="data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute'">
            <if args="typeof element[attribute] === 'object'">
                <if args="element[attribute].label">
                    <text args="element[attribute].label"/>
                </if>
                <ifnot args="element[attribute].label">
                    <if args="element[attribute].value">
                        <text args="element[attribute].value"/>
                    </if>
                </ifnot>
            </if>
            <if args="typeof element[attribute] === 'string'">
                <text args="element[attribute]"/>
            </if><br/>
        </each>
    </each>
</if>
```

This helps in removing empty space if a company name not exists.

Comment: this is not working, is we have to add requirejsconfig file for this @ Shyam Krishna Sreekumar ?