# Magento 2 How to override third party html template in my Module

Tags: magento2, checkout

Magento 2 How to override third party .html template in my Module

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/188790/55981

Answer (score 2):

You can override it in your custom theme.

**Example :**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html

In your custom theme the folder structure would be:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Custom_Theme/Vendor_Module/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html

After this run command:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: I override in custom theme but it won't work, why because first theme files will call next module files will call by sequence.

Comment: @nagendra In Google Chrome go into developer mode (F12 or CTRL + SHIFT + i), then "Network" and reload page. Then you can see exactly what file that you need to override. 

Just click on default.html and see the path.