# Magento 2.3 version Shipping address add company name

Tags: magento2.3, shipping, additional-information

Want to add company name in shipping information in magento 2.3 version. On checkout page company name are not shown in shipping information section.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

For add field in shipping adress section, 
override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html`

For override create `requirejs-config.js` at

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html':
                'Vendor_Module/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html',

            'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html':
                'Vendor_Module/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html'
        }
    }
};
```

Now add `<!-- ko text: address().company --><!-- /ko -->` in overrided file where you want to  display company field.

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html


<div class="shipping-address-item" data-bind="css: isSelected() ? 'selected-item' : 'not-selected-item'">
    <!-- ko text: address().prefix --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().firstname --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko text: address().lastname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().suffix --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: address().street --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: address().company -->
    <!-- ko text: address().city --><!-- /ko -->, <!-- ko text: address().region --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: address().postcode --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: getCountryName(address().countryId) --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko text: address().telephone --><!-- /ko --><br/>
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element' } -->
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: Object.keys(element), as: 'attribute' } -->
            <!-- ko text: element[attribute].value --><!-- /ko -->
         <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: (address().isEditable()) -->
    <button type="button"
            class="action edit-address-link"
            data-bind="click: editAddress, visible: address().isEditable()">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
    </button>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: selectAddress" class="action action-select-shipping-item">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Ship Here'"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Note: On Magento 2.3+ the template is slightly less complex you would just add this under the name line for both templates.

```
<text args="address().company"/><br/>
```

Comment: But in 2.3 version  vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html on this path i have not knockout code. code are change

Comment: <text args="address().company"/> or <text args="address().companyname"/>

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

To add the company name on the shipping address and the side summary and the invoice address displayed on the payment page do the following:

You have to create a custom module in app/code/My/Module

see https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/

Then create in this module the file  /app/code/My/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Checkout/template/billing-address/details.html':
            'My_Module/template/billing-address/details.html',

        'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html':
            'My_Module/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html',

        'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html':
            'My_Module/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html'
    }
}
};
```

Then in your custom theme folder copy the file from:
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html

To: /app/design/frontend/Your/Theme/My_Module/web/template/billing-address/details.html

Change the file in the theme folder to add the company name.

add:

```
<if args="currentBillingAddress().company">
    <text args="currentBillingAddress().company"/><br/>
</if>
```

From: /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html

To: /app/design/frontend/Your/Theme/My_Module/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html

add:

```
<if args="address().company">
    <text args="address().company"/><br/>
</if>
```

From: /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html

To: /app/design/frontend/Your/Theme/My_Module/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html

add:

```
<if args="address().company">
    <text args="address().company"/><br/>
</if>
```

Then run setup:upgrade flush cache etc.

see also: [How to display company name on checkout page in Magento 2.1?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188759/how-to-display-company-name-on-checkout-page-in-magento-2-1)